# I want to separate my page in 3 lines

Tags: html, css

I need help.
I'm tring to make a web pabe with html, css codes.
So I started and now I'm having a little problem.
I want to separate my page into 3 different ones, something like this:

[image]

I hope you understand what I mean.
I want to do this beacause when I set a table on a page it goes under the CSS table (or it called Metro), so I figured out that i could separate the page and put in order everything without interuption.

Thanks for helping!
I'm young so i'm learning. :D

Comment: Show us what you've tried and what specifically you need help with. Give us a [mcve] of your code so far so we have something to work with.

Comment: If you want to i could send it on your email, the files

Comment: no. I suggest you read about how to ask questions on SO http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Panda! If you're creating the layout with tables - try to avoid that! I would start by checking a few basic resources such as: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp or https://www.codementor.io/css/tutorial/4-different-layout-techniques-create-single-page

Comment: Well I'm 17year old, I'm totally new on this site, so I don't know how it works yet.
The basic codes and algorithm, I found them there, but this one I did not..
I'm new at this I need to learn..
Sorry for a bad English, it's not my national language..

Comment: maybe try using bootstrap

Comment: Hey panda, as suggested above bootstrap is a good recommendation. It's a layout framework that will allow you to easily structure pages. I also HIGHLY suggest you look into flexbox and the BEM methodology for naming classes in HTML. All three of these concepts will have you on your way to creating layouts for your pages much easier... Good luck!

Comment: @Panda *"Well I'm 17year old, I'm totally new on this site, so I don't know how it works yet."* You can read, can't you? I've linked you to 2 resources. Take the time to read how to ask a good question. Personally emailing me your code doesn't help the SO community. And none of us gets paid. You need to put as much effort into asking a proper question as you expect for people go give you when they provide an answer.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Okay thanks for the tips :D I'll read it promise

Comment: @ZachHarriott Okay I'll, thanks :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to try to help based on what you've said but I need to let you know that it would be much easier to give you a precise answer if you include what you've done and how (via code). The screenshot does give me an idea of what you're looking for though so here are my thoughts.

What I would do to accomplish this is:

1. Wrap the entire page in a container div so that you can control the display of the items within the page separate from the body of the actual page.
2. Separate Box A and Boxes B and C into two separate divs (rows)
3. Specify the container div as a flexbox which allows you to control the flow and other properties of the rows as flex items. By default the flex-direction property is set to row, so I'll need to change this later to get the layout you wanted.
4. Specify the flex-direction of the container as column.
5. Specify the second row as a flexbox and play with the width of the two boxes inside until you have the proportion you like.

Here's the HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row-1">
        <div class="box-a">Box A</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-2">
        <div class="box-b">Box B</div>
        <div class="box-c">Box C</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
/*Positioning*/

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row-2 {
  display: flex;
}


.box-a {
  background-color: red;
  height: 350px;
}

.box-b {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 350px;
  width: 30%;
}

.box-c {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 70%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

Here's all the code in a pen.
http://codepen.io/zharriott/pen/yMpZge

Hope this helped! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Would love to know why this was downvoted. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: It is pretty useful, ijust needed time to figure out how to set them together :3
Thanks :D

Comment: Awesome, glad to help! Do make sure you mark an answer that answered your question as the answer using the green check mark. It's a little pat on the back for those answering you.

Comment: Okay I did :D If someone doesn't find this answer useful just to let you know that there are programs that doesn't load or recognize thes codes...